# Unchecked Checkbox is causing AJAX Feedback to hang (with spinning loading icon)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, forms

Paul here. I'm working on a simple form with one checkbox, a textarea and some inputs. I got POST to database to work on my localhost, I can submit all form data successfully, but having trouble when a checkbox in my form is unchecked: feedback fails, it says 'please wait' and just spins. The database registers the data okay in either case, but I would appreciate any help to get it more responsive.

The main problem occurs when user leaves 'subscribe' unchecked: no feedback.

I'm also hoping to learn how to create deeper feedback, such as "Your message has been sent. We'll be in touch shortly. You have also been added to our mailing list."

Here is my php:

```
<?php
/*Contact Form*/
//ajax call
if(isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action'] == 'contact'){
    mysql_connect('localhost','******','**********');   
    mysql_select_db('*******');

    //sanitize data
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact-email']);

    //validate email address - check if input was empty
    if(empty($email)){
        $status = 'error';
        $message = 'You did not enter an email address!';
    }
    else if(!preg_match('/^[^\W][a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $email)){ //validate email address - check if is a valid email address
        $status = "error";
        $message = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
    }
    else {
        $existingContact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contact WHERE contact_email_address='$email'");   
        if(mysql_num_rows($existingContact) < 1){

            //database insert code

            $message = $_POST['contact-textarea'];
            $checkbox = $_POST['contact-checkbox'];
            $name = $_POST['contact-name'];
            $date = date('Y-m-d');
            $time = date('H:i:s');

            $insertContact = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact (contact_email_address, contact_date, contact_time, contact_name, contact_message, contact_checkbox) VALUES ('$email','$date','$time','$name','$message','$checkbox')");
            if($insertContact){
                $status = 'success';
                $message = 'your message has been received';    
            }
            else {
                $status = 'error';
                $message = "Oops, there's been a technical error!"; 
            }
        }
        else {
            $status = 'error';
            $message = 'This email address has already been registered!';
        }
    }

    //return the JSON response
    $data = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

    exit;
}
?>
```

and here is my html:

```
    <form id="contact-form" action="?action=contact" method="post">
        <legend>Contact us:</legend>

        <label for="email">Your email: *</label>
        <input type="email" name="contact-email" id="contact-email" placeholder="Your email here..." required></input>

        <label for="name">Your Name: *</label>
        <input type="name" name="contact-name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Your name here..." required></input>

        <label for="message">Your Message: *</label>
        <textarea id="contact-textarea" name="contact-textarea" placeholder="Type your message here..." rows = "8" cols = "35" required></textarea>

        <label for="checkbox">Subscribe to Newsletter?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="contact-checkbox" id="contact-checkbox" value="1"></input>

        <p id="contact-response"></p>

        <input type="submit" name="contact-button" id="contact-button"></input>

    </form>
```

and here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#contact-form').submit(function(){

    //check the form is not currently submitting
    if($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting'){ 

        //setup variables
        var form = $(this),
            formData = form.serialize(),
            formUrl = form.attr('action'),
            formMethod = form.attr('method'), 
            responseMsg = $('#contact-response');

        //add status data to form
        form.data('formstatus','submitting');

        //show response message - waiting
        responseMsg.hide()
                   .addClass('response-waiting')
                   .text('Please Wait...')
                   .fadeIn(200);

        //send data to server
        $.ajax({
            url: formUrl,
            type: formMethod,
            data: formData,
            success:function(data){

                //setup variables
                var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), 
                    klass = '';


                //response conditional
                switch(responseData.status){
                    case 'error':
                        klass = 'response-error';
                    break;
                    case 'success':
                        klass = 'response-success';
                    break;  
                }

                //show reponse message
                responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                           .addClass(klass)
                           .text(responseData.message)
                           .fadeIn(200,function(){
                               //set timeout to hide response message
                               setTimeout(function(){
                                   responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                                       $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                       form.data('formsstatus','idle');
                                   });
                               },3000)
                            });
                }); 
            }
        });
    }
    //prevent form from submitting
    return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: You don't appear to be testing the value of the checkbox within php. Are you sure that isn't causing an error inserting into the database? The behavior you describe is consistent with php returning a 500 server error.

Comment: Yes I needed to test within PHP, with the if statement, 1 or 0. See MarkvA's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that it has to do with the fact that jQuery.serialize does not serialize the checkbox if it is unchecked.

Compare:

**Checked:** contact-email=test%40gmail.com&contact-name=test&contact-textarea=test&contact-checkbox=1 
**Unchecked:** contact-email=test%40gmail.com&contact-name=test&contact-textarea=test

As a result, $_POST['contact-checkbox'] returns null which probably changes the data that's being returned to include a PHP warning, which breaks the JSON you're returning. To fix it, try this (I'm not fully sure it'll work):

```
if ( isset($_POST['contact-checkbox']) ) {
    $checkbox = $_POST['contact-checkbox'];
}
else {
    $checkbox = 0;
}
```

This checks if the contact checkbox is being posted. If so, if sets the checkbox value to the POST value. If not, the checkbox's set to 0.

Comment: That worked ;) The only thing now is that if it returns negative feedback such as 'user already exists', the submit button doesn't do anything. Maybe I'm missing some kind of reset?

Comment: Looks like you misspelled 'form**s**status' in form.data('formsstatus','idle');, which causes the IF check to fail.

Comment: ok I've fixed spelling, and I put it on my web server. Here is a link:http://butterflyepidemic.com/ but now the form (at the bottom) doesn't work at all. The top form does though, so I seem to have set up the database alright. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'll need to see the code for both of those contact forms. I think your best bet is to create a new question on Stack Overflow for this, and then link that question here and I'll have a look tonight/tomorrow.

Comment: I simply forgot to add the credentials for the 2nd form when going to the web host, my bad. It's working now though! :D

Comment: I've created a new question for this here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606470/php-logic-for-a-checkbox-where-i-have-2-forms-and-2-mysql-tables)