# PHP Logic for a Checkbox where I have 2 forms and 2 MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, forms, logic, subscription

Paul here. I have 2 forms:

- a simple 'Signup for news' input for email, and button.
- a 'Contact' form with name, email, message. I also have a checkbox to allow sign up to news from this form.

You can see them here on a page called test:
http://butterflyepidemic.com/test/

I'm not sure how to set up the logic for the checkbox so that both forms are behaving themselves. If a subscriber uses the signup form, and then wants to send us a message, the contact form simply won't let them progress:

> 'this email address has already been registered'

. Ideally I'm thinking we should just accept the message regardless of previous registration, or checkbox status. The feedback would always have something positive to say:

> 'your message has been received'

or

> 'your message has been received. Your email's already signed up here'

, if not two positive messages:

> 'your message has been received and you have been signed up'

I'm new to responsive forms. I initially based my development on this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-sleek-ajax-signup-form/

which uses JS, jQuery, PHP, MySQL, JSON. But now I've a 2nd form with more stuff. I was able to get both forms to check both tables for both fields successfully, but now it's  feedback logic is wrong. (edit: I mean the PHP for 'contact' form)

HTML for 'signup' form:

```
    <form id="newsletter-signup" action="?action=signup" method="post">
        <label for="signup-email">Sign up for news & events:</label>
        <input type="email" name="signup-email" id="signup-email" placeholder="Your email here..."></input>
        <input type="submit" name="signup-button" id="signup-button" value="Sign Me Up!"></input>
        <p id="signup-response"></p>
    </form>
```

and HTML for 'contact' form:

```
    <form id="contact-form" action="?action=contact" method="post">
        <legend>Contact us:</legend>

        <label for="email">Your email: *</label>
        <input type="email" name="contact-email" id="contact-email" placeholder="Your email here..." required></input>

        <label for="name">Your Name: *</label>
        <input type="name" name="contact-name" id="contact-name" placeholder="Your name here..." required></input>

        <label for="message">Your Message: *</label>
        <textarea id="contact-textarea" name="contact-textarea" placeholder="Type your message here..." rows = "8" cols = "35" required></textarea>

        <label for="checkbox">Subscribe to Newsletter?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="contact-checkbox" id="contact-checkbox" value="1"></input>

        <p id="contact-response"></p>

        <input type="submit" name="contact-button" id="contact-button"></input>

    </form>
```

Here's the PHP for the signup form:

```
<?php
//form 1 - signup
//email signup ajax call 
if(isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action'] == 'signup'){
    mysql_connect('***','***','***');  
    mysql_select_db('***');


    //sanitize data
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['signup-email']);

    //validate email address - check if input was empty
    if(empty($email)){
        $status = 'error';
        $message = 'You did not enter an email address!';
    }

    else if(!preg_match('/^[^\W][a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $email)){ //validate email address - check if is a valid email address
        $status = 'error';
        $message = 'You have entered an invalid email address!';
    }
    else {

        $existingSignup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `signups`, `contact` WHERE signup_email_address='$email' OR contact_email_address='$email'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($existingSignup) < 1){
            $date = date('Y-m-d');
            $time = date('H:i:s');

            $insertSignup = mysql_query("INSERT INTO signups (signup_email_address, signup_date, signup_time) VALUES ('$email','$date','$time')");
            if($insertSignup){
                $status = 'success';
                $message = 'you have been signed up!';  
            }
            else {
                $status = 'error';
                $message = "Oops, there's been a technical error! You have not been signed up.";    
            } 
        }

        else {
            $status = 'error';
            $message = 'This email address has already been registered!';
        }
    }

    //return JSON response
    $data = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

    exit;
}
```

and PHP for the contact form follows:

```
/*Contact Form*/
//ajax call
if(isset($_GET['action'])&& $_GET['action'] == 'contact'){
    mysql_connect('***','***','***');
    mysql_select_db('***');


    //sanitize data
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact-email']);

    //validate email address - check if input was empty
    if(empty($email)){
        $status = 'error';
        $message = 'You did not enter an email address!';
    }
    else if(!preg_match('/^[^\W][a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/', $email)){ //validate email address - check if is a valid email address
        $status = "error";
        $message = "You have entered an invalid email address!";
    }
    else {
        $existingContact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `signups`, `contact` WHERE signup_email_address='$email' OR contact_email_address='$email'");   
        if(mysql_num_rows($existingContact) < 1){
            //mysql_free_result($existingContact);
            //database insert code

            if ( isset($_POST['contact-checkbox']) ) {
                $checkbox = $_POST['contact-checkbox'];
            }
            else {
                $checkbox = 0;
            }

            $message = $_POST['contact-textarea'];
            $name = $_POST['contact-name'];
            $date = date('Y-m-d');
            $time = date('H:i:s');

            $insertContact = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact (contact_email_address, contact_date, contact_time, contact_name, contact_message, contact_checkbox) VALUES ('$email','$date','$time','$name','$message','$checkbox')");
            if($insertContact){
                $status = 'success';
                $message = 'your message has been received';    
            }
            else if ($insertContact && $checkbox = $_POST['contact-checkbox']){
                $status = 'success';
                $message = "your message has been received and you have been signed up";        
            }

            else {
                $status = 'error';
                $message = "Oops, there's been a technical error!"; 
            }
        }

        else {
            $status = 'error';
            $message = 'This email address has already been registered!';
        }
    }

    //return the JSON response
    $data = array(
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $message
    );

    echo json_encode($data);

    exit;
}
?>
```

JS for 'signup' form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#newsletter-signup').submit(function(){

    //check the form is not currently submitting
    if($(this).data('formsstatus') !== 'submitting'){

        //setup variables
        var form = $(this),
        formData = form.serialize(),
        formUrl = form.attr('action'),
        formMethod = form.attr('method'), 
        responseMsg = $('#signup-response');

        //add status data to form
        form.data('formsstatus','submitting');

        //show response message - waiting
        responseMsg.hide()
                   .addClass('response-waiting')
                   .text('Please Wait...')
                   .fadeIn(200);

        //send data to server to be validated
        $.ajax({
            url: formUrl,
            type: formMethod,
            data: formData,
            success:function(data){
                //setup variables
                var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), 
                    klass = '';

                //response conditional
                switch(responseData.status){
                    case 'error':
                        klass = 'response-error';
                    break;
                    case 'success':
                        klass = 'response-success';
                    break;  
                }

                //show reponse message
                responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                           .addClass(klass)
                           .text(responseData.message)
                           .fadeIn(200,function(){
                               //set timeout to hide response message
                               setTimeout(function(){
                                   responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                                       $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                       form.data('formsstatus','idle');
                                   });
                               },3000)
                            });
                });
            }
        });
    }
    //prevent form from submitting
    return false;
    });
})
```

and finally the JS for the 'contact' form (pretty much the same as for 'signup'):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#contact-form').submit(function(){

    //check the form is not currently submitting
    if($(this).data('formsstatus') !== 'submitting'){ 

        //setup variables
        var form = $(this),
            formData = form.serialize(),
            formUrl = form.attr('action'),
            formMethod = form.attr('method'), 
            responseMsg = $('#contact-response');

        //add status data to form
        form.data('formsstatus','submitting');

        //show response message - waiting
        responseMsg.hide()
                   .addClass('response-waiting')
                   .text('Please Wait...')
                   .fadeIn(200);

        //send data to server
        $.ajax({
            url: formUrl,
            type: formMethod,
            data: formData,
            success:function(data){

                //setup variables
                var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data), 
                    klass = '';


                //response conditional
                switch(responseData.status){
                    case 'error':
                        klass = 'response-error';
                    break;
                    case 'success':
                        klass = 'response-success';
                    break;  
                }

                //show reponse message
                responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('response-waiting')
                           .addClass(klass)
                           .text(responseData.message)
                           .fadeIn(200,function(){
                               //set timeout to hide response message
                               setTimeout(function(){
                                   responseMsg.fadeOut(200,function(){
                                       $(this).removeClass(klass);
                                       form.data('formsstatus','idle');
                                   });
                               },3000)
                            });
                }); 
            }
        });
    }
    //prevent form from submitting
    return false;
    });
})
```

That's it for the code. I would like to learn how I can set up the logic to give appropriate feedback as in the ideal examples above the code please. I would be happy with any keywords/links/examples of what I may need to research. Thanks, Paul.

Comment: That's a **wall of code**. Can you narrow it down to the areas where you are having difficulties with?

Comment: Yeah, in the PHP contact form, from the line: `code`  $existingContact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `signups`, `contact` WHERE signup_email_address='$email' OR contact_email_address='$email'");  `code`

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? What is apropriate feedback? And what is wrong with the feedback you get (if you get any)?

Comment: my problem is with feedback logic, particularly targeting the variable that tells if checkbox has been checked or not, so that we can display a corresponding message to the user. What's wrong are several things now that I think of it. At the moment if the checkbox is unchecked, user should not be subscribed, right? But If they try to subscribe, oh, they already are. Anyone know how to target the variable for when checkbox has or has not been checked? Cheers :)

Comment: OK, just thinking out loud here: In the contact form, I could create a separate table field for emails (required) who do not wish to be subscribed. That way in MySQL, the signup form can be told not to search that group. The other problem is that if the user subscribes then they can't send us a message because they are subscribed. Okay, I'll try creating a new database field called non_subscribed_emails or something and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

Step 1: Create a third MySQL table called 'contact_only' in phpmyadmin for people who want to message only (no sign-up)

```
CREATE TABLE `contact_only` (
  `contact_only_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact_only_email_address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_only_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_only_message` varchar(3000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_only_checkbox` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `contact_only_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `contact_only_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`contact_only_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Step 2: in the 'contact' form php, use 'if & else if' to give appropriate feedback based on whether user ticked the checkbox or not

```
if ( isset($_POST['contact-checkbox']) ) {

    $existingContact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `signups`, `contact` WHERE signup_email_address='$email' OR contact_email_address='$email'");  
    if(mysql_num_rows($existingContact) < 1){

        $checkbox = $_POST['contact-checkbox'];
        $message = $_POST['contact-textarea'];
        $name = $_POST['contact-name'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $time = date('H:i:s');

        $insertContact = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact (contact_email_address, contact_date, contact_time, contact_name, contact_message, contact_checkbox) VALUES ('$email','$date','$time','$name','$message','$checkbox')");

        if($insertContact){
            $status = 'success';
            $message = 'your message has been received and you have been signed up';        
        }
    }
    else {

        $checkbox = $_POST['contact-checkbox'];
        $message = $_POST['contact-textarea'];
        $name = $_POST['contact-name'];
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        $time = date('H:i:s');

        $insertContact = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact (contact_email_address, contact_date, contact_time, contact_name, contact_message, contact_checkbox) VALUES ('$email','$date','$time','$name','$message','$checkbox')");

        $status = 'success';
        $message = 'Message received. Note - this email address has already been subscribed!';
    }
}
else if (isset($_POST['contact-checkbox']) == false){
    $checkbox = 0;
    $message = $_POST['contact-textarea'];
    $name = $_POST['contact-name'];
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $time = date('H:i:s');

    $insertContactOnly = mysql_query("INSERT INTO contact_only (contact_only_email_address, contact_only_date, contact_only_time, contact_only_name, contact_only_message, contact_only_checkbox) VALUES ('$email','$date','$time','$name','$message','$checkbox')");

    if ($insertContactOnly) {
        $status = 'success';
        $message = 'your message has been received';
    }           
}

else {
    $status = 'error';
    $message = "Oops, there's been a technical error!"; 
}
```

I am happy with this way because it generally gives more positive than negative feedback, and is always appropriate. Here is the link to this solution:

http://butterflyepidemic.com/test/

If you know how to make it faster or more efficient, please let me know! Thanks, Paul